# Dividing up a fortune

Tags: proof-explanation

I am trying to solve this below problem:

> At his death, a millionaire left his 10 children a million dollars in cash, all in $\$100$, $\$10$, $\$1$ bills,10-cent, and 1-cent coins.  Show that there is a way for them to split the fortune into ten stacks of equal value.  (Note that this would not be true if there were $\$3$ bills).

So the best I can do is set this up as solving an equation in five variables. I want to find $a,b,c,d,e$ so that
$$ 
10^6 = a \cdot 100 + b \cdot 10 + c \cdot 1 + d \cdot 0.1 + e \cdot .01.
$$
I can try to take congruences mod $10$. The LHS is clearly $0$, and any multiple of $10$ is certainly $0$, but $\frac{1}{10}$ is not even defined in $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$, since that would amount to division by zero, so this strategy does not work.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to get started?

Comment: If you don't have integers for all your coefficients, multiply by powers of ten until they are.

Comment: Note that this will also be possible if some of the money is in \$1,000 and in \$10,000 and in \$100,000 bills.

Answer (score 2):

First, prove that the number of 1-cent coins is divisible by 10. This follows from the fact that "cents place" of \$1 million is zero. Then, WLOG, exchange the 1-cent coins for an equivalent number of 10-cent coins.

Then, prove that the number of 10-cent coins is divisible by 10. This follows from the fact that there are no 1-cent coins, and the "10-cent place" of \$1 million is zero. Then, exchange the 10-cent coins for an equivalent number of \$1 coins.

...

Then, prove there must be a multiple of 10 \$100 bills. This is because all the currency now is in \$100 bills.

Comment: I don't know how I would go about proving any of these, though. Would you mind walking me through one of them?

Comment: @HansEngler You're right, the trick is that you have to trade in the pennies for dimes after proving there's a multiple of ten of them, then trade in the dimes for \$ bills after proving there's a multiple of 10 of them, etc. I forgot to add that part.

Comment: So this proof sketch shows that a division into stacks of equal value would also be possible if there were 10,000 heirs :)

Comment: @HansEngler Correct, because we could always amalgamate the fortune into piles of exactly \$100

Comment: @MarkSaving I'm still not fully sure that I understand. I suppose the idea is that because $10^6$ ends in a $0$, if I had a number of pennies not a multiple of $10$, I'd have some "change" modulo $10$, and adding any multiple of either dimes, dollars, and so forth, also divisible by $10$ in cents, wouldn't recover this. The intuition is ok, but is there a way to formalize that? I feel that my understanding is a bit shaky.

Comment: @AlgebraMaster To make things more precise, we will show that for all n from 0 to 5, we can arrange the money into a collection of $n$-piles, where an $n$-pile is a collection of money work $10^m$ cents for some $m$ such that $n <= m <= 5$. We do this by induction. The money is already arranged into $0$-piles initially, so the base case is covered. For the inductive step, suppose we have arranged the money into $n$-piles. The total amount of money is 0 mod $10^{n+1}$ cents, so there must be a multiple of 10 piles with exactly $10^n$ cents in value. We can group these into groups of 10.